# Can energy of one field be converted to another?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, particle-physics, gravitational-waves

From school we know examples of energy conversions: from electromagnetic to electric, from electric to heat, from heat to electromagnetic, etc.

However, obviously this almost has nothing to do with conversion, because as heat, as electricity, as friction, and so on are electromagnetic field energy.

But what if there is some electrically charged and massive particle moving at constant velocity and being accelerated by gravitational field, and not electrical.

Will it emit (scatter) gravitational wave (quants) instead of electromagnetic, or both?

Also in opposite situation, same particle, accelerated by em field radiates photon, only because of electromagnetic interaction, or it emits photon (and gravitational waves) independently on the type of interaction?

Comment: this may help https://www.britannica.com/science/energy

Comment: @annav I have read, but it does not give the answers